# Capybara fetch wrong URL

Tags: ruby, devise, capybara

in form html.erb code:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name), html: {class: "form-signin", role: "form"}) do |f| %>
```

which is generate html element:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users/sign_in" class="form-signin" id="new_user" method="post" role="form">
```

in my `login_steps.rb` code:

```
fill_in 'user_email', with: "admin@test.com"
fill_in 'user_password', with: "12345678"
click_button 'Sign in'
```

it return error
No route matches [GET] "/users/2"

why it return GET method instead POST? also the URL changed from "/users/sign_in" to "/users/2"

it's possible capybara fetch/generate wrong url?

Comment: As a guess -  I would say whatever controller is handling /user/sign_in is redirecting to /users/2 on either success or failure - your test.log will show you whats happening

Comment: yep. it's redirected from the controller. thanks!